# Как вызвать диалог выбора пользователей?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как с помощью WinAPI вызвать диалог выбора пользователей и групп?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этих целей служит [Directory Object Picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675899(v=vs.85).aspx), использовать его можно примерно так:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Objsel.h>

#include <wrl/client.h>

#include <array>
#include <memory>

::HRESULT
Verify_Succeeded(const ::HRESULT hr)
{
    if(!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    return(hr);
}

void
Spawn_PickUserDialog(const ::HWND parent)
{
    ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IDsObjectPicker> p_object_picker{};
    // создаем
    Verify_Succeeded
    (
        ::CoCreateInstance
        (
            ::CLSID_DsObjectPicker
        ,   nullptr
        ,   ::CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER
        ,   ::IID_IDsObjectPicker
        ,   &p_object_picker
        )
    );
    // настраиваем много флажков
    {
        ::std::array<::DSOP_SCOPE_INIT_INFO, 1> scope_init_infos{};
        scope_init_infos[0].cbSize = sizeof(scope_init_infos[0]);
        scope_init_infos[0].flType =
        (   0x00000000
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_TARGET_COMPUTER
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_UPLEVEL_JOINED_DOMAIN
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_DOWNLEVEL_JOINED_DOMAIN
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_ENTERPRISE_DOMAIN
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_GLOBAL_CATALOG
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_UPLEVEL_DOMAIN
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_DOWNLEVEL_DOMAIN
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_WORKGROUP
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_USER_ENTERED_UPLEVEL_SCOPE
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_TYPE_USER_ENTERED_DOWNLEVEL_SCOPE
        );
        scope_init_infos[0].flScope =
        (   0x00000000
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_STARTING_SCOPE
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_WANT_DOWNLEVEL_BUILTIN_PATH
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_WANT_PROVIDER_LDAP
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_WANT_PROVIDER_GC
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_WANT_PROVIDER_WINNT
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_WANT_SID_PATH
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_DEFAULT_FILTER_COMPUTERS
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_DEFAULT_FILTER_CONTACTS
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_DEFAULT_FILTER_GROUPS
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_DEFAULT_FILTER_USERS
        |   DSOP_SCOPE_FLAG_DEFAULT_FILTER_SERVICE_ACCOUNTS
        );
        scope_init_infos[0].FilterFlags.Uplevel.flBothModes =
        (   0x00000000
        |   DSOP_FILTER_INCLUDE_ADVANCED_VIEW
        |   DSOP_FILTER_USERS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_BUILTIN_GROUPS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_WELL_KNOWN_PRINCIPALS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_UNIVERSAL_GROUPS_DL
        |   DSOP_FILTER_UNIVERSAL_GROUPS_SE
        |   DSOP_FILTER_GLOBAL_GROUPS_DL
        |   DSOP_FILTER_GLOBAL_GROUPS_SE
        |   DSOP_FILTER_DOMAIN_LOCAL_GROUPS_DL
        |   DSOP_FILTER_DOMAIN_LOCAL_GROUPS_SE
        |   DSOP_FILTER_CONTACTS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_COMPUTERS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_SERVICE_ACCOUNTS
        |   DSOP_FILTER_PASSWORDSETTINGS_OBJECTS
        );
        scope_init_infos[0].FilterFlags.flDownlevel =
        (   0x00000000
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_USERS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_LOCAL_GROUPS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_GLOBAL_GROUPS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_COMPUTERS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_WORLD
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_AUTHENTICATED_USER
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_ANONYMOUS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_BATCH
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_CREATOR_OWNER
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_CREATOR_GROUP
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_DIALUP
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_INTERACTIVE
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_NETWORK
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_SERVICE
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_SYSTEM
        //| DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_EXCLUDE_BUILTIN_GROUPS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_TERMINAL_SERVER
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_ALL_WELLKNOWN_SIDS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_LOCAL_SERVICE
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_NETWORK_SERVICE
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_REMOTE_LOGON
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_INTERNET_USER
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_OWNER_RIGHTS
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_SERVICES
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_LOCAL_LOGON
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_THIS_ORG_CERT
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_IIS_APP_POOL
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_ALL_APP_PACKAGES
        |   DSOP_DOWNLEVEL_FILTER_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS
        );
        // какие аттрибуты выбранных объектов хотим получить
        ::std::array<::LPCWSTR, 3> attributes{L"description", L"name", L"fullName"};
        ::DSOP_INIT_INFO init_info{};
        init_info.cbSize = sizeof(init_info);
        init_info.pwzTargetComputer = nullptr; // локальный компьютер
        init_info.cDsScopeInfos = scope_init_infos.size();
        init_info.aDsScopeInfos = scope_init_infos.data();
        init_info.cAttributesToFetch = attributes.size();
        init_info.apwzAttributeNames = attributes.data();
        init_info.flOptions = DSOP_FLAG_SKIP_TARGET_COMPUTER_DC_CHECK;
        Verify_Succeeded(p_object_picker->Initialize(::std::addressof(init_info)));
    }
    // показываем
    ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IDataObject> p_object{};
    if(S_FALSE != Verify_Succeeded(p_object_picker->InvokeDialog(parent, &p_object)))
    {
        //  p_object содержит результаты
    }
    else
    {
        //  пользователь отменил диалог
    }
}

int main()
{
    Verify_Succeeded(::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, ::COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
    Spawn_PickUserDialog(::GetDesktopWindow());
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```